# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'ggplot'

Tags: python, ggplot2, pycharm

I am a newbie to this field. I'm trying to use `ggplot` library to visualize my data. I am using `pycharm ide`.

However although I installed ggplot through pip and also using settings I get the error saying :

`ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'ggplot'`

Could you please help me with this?

Comment: tried `pip install ggplot`?

Comment: Yes I tried it. I'm using Python 3.7 in a virtual environment. But still gives module not imported error

Comment: Did you checked your  virtual environment setting in your pycharm?

Comment: Hi @scriptboy yes I did. The virtul environment also has Python 3.7.  anything else to try on?

Comment: Is `ggplot` installed on the interpreter? This could be checked in `File - Settings - Project - Project Interpreter`

Comment: Check your `whcih python` and `which pip`, make sure they are in the same path. then run `python` type `import ggplot` see if you can import successfully, if you can, that means you have your pycharm config wrong.

Comment: Hi @user2235698, I have configured as Python 3.7

Comment: @scriptboy, the output shows that it's python 3.7. I checked with import sys
print (sys.version). Even it shows Python 3.7

Comment: Hey I fixed the issue! I edited `utils.py` , `smoothers.py` and 'stat_smooth.py'. It removed the error. I followed the following link,  [https://github.com/yhat/ggpy/issues/662#issuecomment-526826798]. Thank you all for helping me!!